# reduxForm validation issue in Field Component (Error: Maximum update depth exceeded)

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-redux, redux-form

The error message is :
**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

This problem appears only when I add *required* function in validate attribute in Field component. Without *required* all works fine. I don't understand why it doesn't work...

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import React from "react";
import { email, minLength, required } from "../utils/formValidation";
import inputComponent from "./inputComponent";

let AuthForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props;
  const minLength8 = minLength(8);
  return (
    <form className='auth-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} action='/projects'>
      <Field
        id='email'
        name='email'
        type='text'
        label='Email'
        component={inputComponent}
        placeholder='Email'
        validate={[required, email, minLength8]}
      />
      <Field
        id='password'
        name='password'
        label='Password'
        component={inputComponent}
        type='password'
        // validate={[minLength8, required]}
      />
      <button type='submit'>Sign in</button>
    </form>
  );
};

AuthForm = reduxForm({ form: "auth" })(AuthForm);
export default AuthForm;
```

**functions for validation**

```
export const email = (value) =>
  value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value)
    ? "Invalid email address"
    : undefined;

export const minLength = (min) => (value) =>
  value && value.length < min ? `Must be ${min} characters or more` : undefined;

export const maxLength = (max) => (value) =>
  value && value.length > max ? `Must be ${max} characters or less` : undefined;

export const required = (value) =>
  value || typeof value === "number" ? undefined : "Required";
```

**Input component**

```
const inputComponent = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error, warning },
}) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
      {touched &&
        ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
          (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it when I wrapped parents of reduxForm components into connect() function

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was necessary to create the min length before the form, that is, after connecting the import. Don't create minLength function inside AuthForm function